# How to import function from one python script without calling it

Tags: python

I am trying to import a function called `page1` that contains other functions inside of it in a library file so that I can call it inside this file. However, this creates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/antonios/numworks-math-libs/numworksMath.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numworksLibs
  File "/Users/antonios/numworks-math-libs/numworksLibs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numworksMath import page1
  File "/Users/antonios/numworks-math-libs/numworksMath.py", line 35, in <module>
    page1()
  File "/Users/antonios/numworks-math-libs/numworksMath.py", line 29, in page1
    numworksLibs.get_ordered_pair(ordered_pair_num, xs, ys)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numworksLibs' has no attribute 'get_ordered_pair' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I think this is because the main script is importing the library, and the library is importing the main script (circular import). Is there a way that I can get around this in Python? I have tried all solutions from [this](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52484779.shtml#:%7E:text=%23%20You%20can%20run%20the%20function,import%20Python%20modules%20without%20installing.) website and made sure that none of the names conflicted with any Python built-in libraries, as previously mentioned in other posts on SO. `get_ordered_pair` is also defined in the library file.

library file import:

```
from numworksMath import page1
```

a snippet of the main script:

```
import numworksLibs

def page1():
```

`page1` contains code that will run if the function is called without an input, and this happens when importing the file from the Python CLI.

Comment: Importing the main script is usually a code smell in my experience. I'd move the code in `main` that you're importing out to its own file, then have `main` import them.

Comment: What does your actual code look like?

Comment: @JammyDodger Do you want all my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would really want to do in this situation is to create a separate file like @Carcigenicate mentioned. with all the code that you are importing more than once and have each script import this. For me, I made a file called `main.py` with all the code that needed to be imported more than once, and then both the library file and the main script importing this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can guard your code by checking if the file is being run as a script or if it's being imported as a module. To do this you need to check if the current `__name__` is set to `'__main__'`.

If your file looks like this:

```
def foo():
    ...

foo()
```

Simply change it to only run `foo` when `__name__` is `'__main__'`

```
def foo():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Now `foo` will only automatically run if you call python on the file directly, and not if it is simply imported.

Comment: This did not work for me. It broke some functionality. What @Carcigenicate mentioned in my comment is what worked. I'm turning that into an answer. I had mentioned in the question that this did not work.

Comment: @NotAnerd If that does not work for you, I highly suggest refactoring the modules which rely on import side-effects to operate. This will burn you badly in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, You're right. I have taken measures against that now.